# Globe of invulnerability vs non-magical effects of spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does the D&D 5e Globe of Invulnerability protect people from non-magical effects that are the results of spells? What if a spell produces an effect outside the globe directed into it?

For example, suppose that one hurls an object with a spell or causes the ceiling to cave in?  A *stone bolt* might be another example.  Indeed, even *fire bolt* or *burning hands* fits with this question given that the fire is not produced within the globe—it is produced outside and shot within it.

My thought was that this would be a good test case to let me know how magic and anti-magic should interact.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Questions should have tags indicating the system the question's about. You can [edit] that in yourself or leave a Comment and someone will add it for you. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Grim Harvest trigger when my Teleport causes a death?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72611/does-grim-harvest-trigger-when-my-teleport-causes-a-death)

Answer (score 8):

Globe of Invulnerability states:

> Any spell ... can't affect creatures within it, ... Such a spell can target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them. Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

First the globe *only* affects spells; effects that are **not** spells can get through *even if they are magical in nature*.  For example, a bard's *Cutting Words*, a Cleric's *Turn Undead*, a Monk's *Ki*, a Paladin's *Smite*, a Sorcerer's *Wild Surge* (unless it says "you cast ...") or a Warlock's *Hurl through Hell* are all unaffected.  Similarly, the effects of magical items (unless they say "you cast ...") ignore the globe.  (+1 spear works, magic missiles cast by wands would not).

Further, there is nothing in the wording of the spell that prevents the people and objects within the globe from being affected by spells *indirectly*.  For example, a person standing on a rope bridge protected by the globe is still going to fall if I target the parts of the bridge *outside* the globe with a disintegrate spell. Similarly, I can Conjure Animals outside the globe and send them into the globe to bite you.

Then there are the edge cases.

For example, Conjure Barrage says "You throw a nonmagical weapon ... into the air to create a cone of identical weapons that shoot forward ..."

This one could be interpreted either way: if it is an area of effect type spell then the globe will block it if it is the creation of arrows, say, outside the globe which get flung by the spell then it should get through.  You will need to work these ones out with your DM.

Answer (score -1):

I say no, the globe won't protect form non-magical effects indirectly caused by spells. But, I would be more strict about the magical nature of the indirect effect. The fire caused by burning hands is still magical.

I interpreted this spell as *an anti magic field for spells of 5th level and lower.* For example, a Bigby's hand (4th level) that was created outside the globe would be suppressed if the caster move it within the radius of the globe to punch or grapple the caster's globe.