# Does Aura of Warding protect you from Warding Bond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If a Cleric that cast Warding Bond is in the Aura of an Ancients Paladin, does he take half damage from Warding Bond?

Aura of Warding:

> You and friendly creatures within 10 feet of you have resistance to **damage from spells.**

Warding Bond:

> Also, each time it takes damage, **you take the same amount of damage.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Aura of Warding grant resistance to physical damage from spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90310/does-aura-of-warding-grant-resistance-to-physical-damage-from-spells)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Rules as Intended: No

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/805222825183219712) has clarified:

> Q: Is warding bond the source of its generated damage instance? If so what damage type is it? Is it still spell damage? thanks
>
> A: When you take damage via warding bond, you're taking damage from whatever caused damage to the target of warding bond.

So, according to Jeremy's clarification, the damage you receive from *warding bond* is considered the same source as what damaged the ward. Thus, the only time *aura of warding* would work on it is if that original damage was caused by a spell.

As always, it is up to the DM to decide how much designer clarifications and intent means at their table.

Comment: Related:[Does Warding Bond carry over damage type?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/does-warding-bond-carry-over-damage-type?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

Because Warding Bond is a spell, Aura of Warding would make you resistant to it's effects.

> "This ***spell*** wards a willing creature you touch and creates a mystic connection between you and the target until the spell ends."