# If the Bestow Curse spell causes me to do extra damage, does the target's death trigger the Necromancy wizard's Grim Harvest feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, wizard, necromancy

In D&D 5e using a wizard of the School of Necromancy:

If I cast *bestow curse* on a monster, then kill it with a crossbow, would it trigger the Grim Harvest feature due to the extra 1d8 damage? Does it matter if the monster had 1 HP?

What about if I cast *bestow curse*, then hit it with *magic missile* (and kill it with just 1 missile) - would Grim Harvest trigger off the missile or the curse?

Comment: Some related questions you may find helpful: "[Does killing a creature with a Shadow Blade trigger the Necromancy Wizard's Grim Harvest feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127644)" and "[Does Grim Harvest trigger when my Teleport causes a death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72611)" and "[Does Grim Harvest trigger when my minions kill something?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72608)"

Comment: For future reference we don't generally like reposting a question, it is better to edit them. On the other hand, it looks like you tried that but it was sent through review because you have accidentally made two accounts, which you might want to get [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). But actually, I'll just remove the [other posting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170579/52137) (linked for the benefit of 10k's) and we'll call this a learning experience and move forward as though nothing's happened.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Grim Harvest triggers only when a spell kills a creature.

[Grim Harvest](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofNecromancy) reads:

> when you kill one or more creatures **with a spell** of 1st level or higher, you regain hit points equal to twice the spell’s level

[Bestow Curse](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bestow-curse) reads:

> **your attacks** and **spells** deal an extra 1d8 necrotic damage

So to your first question, the 1d8 necrotic damage is added *to your attack*, so it is not considered damage from the spell, it is from your attack.

To your second question, the 1d8 necrotic is added to the damage of Magic Missile, a spell, so Grim Harvest would trigger based on the level you cast Magic Missile at (assuming it killed its target).

The easy way to remember it is:

**Bestow Curse does not deal damage, so it cannot reduce a target's hitpoints to zero.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It makes a lot of sense.