# Does a Life Cleric's Disciple of Life feature apply to healing effects of summoned creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, summoning

The [Life Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain)'s [Disciple of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DiscipleofLife-131) feature improves the effect of healing spells:

> Also starting at 1st level, your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level.

Does Disciple of Life apply to the healing provided by creatures summoned by spells?

For example, if the Life Cleric casts [Summon Celestial](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-celestial) and the Celestial uses its Healing Touch, would that benefit from Disciple of Life?

The same would presumably apply to spells such as [Conjure Celestial](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-celestial) ([Unicorn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17042-unicorn)'s Healing Touch) or [Conjure Woodland Beings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-woodland-beings) ([Dryad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16849-dryad)'s Goodberry).

Comment: Related: [Are Goodberries affected by the Life domain class features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84784/are-goodberries-affected-by-the-life-domain-class-features)

Answer (score 19):

### The healing bonus only applies to the cleric's own healing spells

You have the relevant text right there

> Also starting at 1st level, **your healing spells** are more effective. Whenever **you use a spell** of 1st level or higher **to restore hit points** to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level.

The text explicitly refers to the cleric's own healing spells ("you"). The healing spells that summoned creatures use are **theirs**, not those of the cleric. When such a creature is casting a healing spell or using a healing effect such as Healing Touch (not even a spell), it is not the cleric casting or using a healing spell.

Comment: Casting the summoning spell ultimately led to a creature getting its hit points restored. Couldn't we say that the cleric used their spell to restore hit points?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. The summoning spell is not restoring hit points, it is summoning a creature. That creature then may be able to do many things. Maybe it would be a separate question on how direct an effect needs to be to count as an effect of a spell, but I think it would be hard to answer in general.

Comment: A similar argument can be made for the Goodberry spell: the spell is not restoring hit points, it is creating a berry that heals. So why would goodberry benefit from Disciple of Life, but not a summoning spell?

Comment: The Sage Advice Compendium specifically says the berries benefit from Disciple of Life.

Comment: Related: [Question on Grim Harvest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72608/does-grim-harvest-trigger-when-my-minions-kill-something)

Comment: @GuillaumeF., Goodberry at least does not require *another spell or ability* to restore life points, a summoned creature does. If a summoned creature casts another spell to restore life points, it is that other spell, not your spell that does so. (For what its worth, I find that SA ruling questionable, in my mind using a berry to restore hp is different from using the spell. But of course, unless they revert it like they did with the effect of disintegrate on a shape changed druid, we'll have to abide by it).

Comment: Goodberries' healing is described in the spell itself so it is part of the spell effect. The summoning spells themselves do not describe any healing effects being part of the spell.